# How do I know whether the zip file is password protected or not with dotnetzip?

Tags: dotnetzip

now let's think we got a random zip file so how do I know that file is password protected?
cause there ain't a method like

```
bool IsPasswordProtected(string fileName);
```

I am asking this cause there are couple of methods to extract entries from a zip file
but still I have to use either Extract() or ExtractWithPassword()
but to use this I have to know the file that I am going to extract is actually password protected or not. I know the password applies to the entries not to the zip file itself.
I checked every methods in the documentation but I couldn't find a suitable method to solve this issue or did I miss something?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `ZipEntry.UsesEncryption` property.

Comment: Sorry - I have learned to my cost that I only have enough resources for either supercomputing or VS 2010....choices choices....

Comment: add more system memories so you don't need to close the VS when you open your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the `ZipEntry.Extract` method and if it fails due to missing a password you will get an exception, and then try the `ExtractWithPassword` and see if that works. If it does not work, then fail with the original exception. Unfortunately the `Password` property is write-only.

According to the documentation `ZipEntry.UsesEntryption` is not the same as requiring a password.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);

         if (!password.Equals("")) 
         { 
             zip.Password = password; 
         }

         try 
         {
             if (Directory.Exists(outputDirectory)) 
             { 
                 Directory.Delete(outputDirectory); 
             }

             Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
             zip.ExtractAll(outputDirectory);
             System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unzip process is complete.", "Information");
         }
         catch (BadPasswordException e) 
         {
             string value = "Type password for unzip";
             if (InputBox("Zip file was password protected.", "Password : ",ref value ) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
             {
                 ExtractFileToDirectory(filename, outputpath,value);
             }
         }
```

And InputBox method is follow...

```
public DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        System.Windows.Forms.Label label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonOk = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

        form.Text = title;
        label.Text = promptText;
        textBox.Text = value;

        buttonOk.Text = "OK";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        buttonOk.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;

        label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        label.AutoSize = true;
        textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(396, 107);
        form.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });
        form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
        form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
        value = textBox.Text;
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

The code is useful when zip file have password. If zip file have password, input text dialog appear and request password for extract. Note that (outputDirectory is string that for extract zip file location). I think that code was very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too.i tried the code from Francis Upton .it wasn't useful.
You can try

```
ZipFile.CheckZipPassword(TemporaryFilePath, PassWord);
```

make the  PassWord to null;like...

```
bool ExistPassWord = ZipFile.CheckZipPassword(TemporaryFilePath, null);
```